# Audio Controller malfunctioning

Tags: linux, windows, laptop, audio

I've purchased a new Acer Predator a week ago and has set it up to dual boot with Linux Mint and Windows 10. It was working perfectly fine for a week, until yesterday my sound suddenly disappeared while I was logged in Linux. It happened right after I had plugged my headphones into a headphone jack, which led me to suspect that it was a hardware-related issue.

After reboot, Linux would not recognize any sound outputs. Just to verify my suspicions, I had booted into Windows, which had the same issue: no output devices were recognized, whether it were built-in speakers or headphones. It also has revealed that Intel Audio Controlled was malfunctioning and throwing Error Code 10. Reinstalling/rolling back drivers didn't help, as was expected, but I had to try.

Just for another confirmation, I booted of a USB Linux distro, and it also couldn't detect any audio outputs. Confident that my audio controller was dead, I ordered a replacement laptop and stopped looking for a solution.

The next day, I started the laptop again and the sound was working just fine in Windows, but not Linux. The Intel Audio Controller is now operating properly. No changes were made overnight, and I honestly have no clue why the sudden change of heart.

At this point I'm pretty sure it's a safer bet to replace it, but I can't help but wonder what could've caused the issue and how has it resolved itself despite my hardest efforts?

Comment: Since both OS's appear to not work with it anymore, I would agree it is likely to be a hardware problem. I am sure it is still under warranty of some form so just RMA it and not waste too much other time with it

Comment: As you noted, the issue occurred after plugging in headphones. It could be electrostatic discharge (ESD) zorched the chip or that the phones were shorted or open and the jack circuitry was insufficiently protected. Whatever the cause, since it's a new machine, I'd take it back for repair or replacement (after removing PII from the HDD). BTW, ESD can also destroy a camera memory card, so touch a grounded part of the PC case while holding and inserting a plug or card.